# How do I get my Telegram bot to acknowledge previously seen messages?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Problem:

- Telegram bot doesn't recognise seen messages and keeps responding to the latest message until I send "quit" or crtl-c in command line.

Completely new to python. There may be a flaw in my programming logic.
In 'for last_update_id in updates["result"]' I tried to add 1 to the last_update_id variable after each loop. But the variable doesn't seem to update.

```py
# chatbot.py not included. It trains NN model. 

import json 
import requests
import time
import urllib
import telegram

TOKEN = "xxx"
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)


def get_url(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        content = response.content.decode("utf8")
        return content

def get_json_from_url(url):
        content = get_url(url)
        js = json.loads(content)
        return js


def get_updates(offset): #gets json file from URL
        url = URL + "getUpdates"
        if offset:
                url += "?offset={}".format(offset)
        js = get_json_from_url(url)
        return js

def get_last_update_id(updates):
        update_ids = []
        for update in updates["result"]:
                update_ids.append(int(update["update_id"]))
        return max(update_ids)

def get_last_chat_text(updates):
        num_updates = len(updates["result"])
        last_update = num_updates - 1
        text = updates["result"][last_update]["message"]["text"] #text input
        return text

def get_last_chat_id(updates):
        chat_id = updates["result"][-1]["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        return chat_id


def send_message(output,chat_id):
        bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text = output)
     
def main():
        input_text = get_last_chat_text(updates)
        return input_text                
           

print("Let's chat! (type 'quit' to exit)")
last_update_id = None
while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_update_id) #returns json file
        last_update_id = get_last_update_id(updates) #returns max_update_id

        for last_update_id in updates["result"]:
                main()
                input_text = main()
                if input_text == "quit":
                        break
                input_text = tokenize(input_text)
                X = bag_of_words(input_text, all_words)
                X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
                X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

                output = model(X)
                _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

                tag = tags[predicted.item()]

                probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
                prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
                if prob.item() > 0.75:
                        for intent in intents['intents']:
                                if tag == intent["tag"]:
                                        output = f"{random.choice(intent['responses'])}"
                else:
                        output = f"{bot_name}: I do not understand..."

                print(output)

                chat_id = get_last_chat_id(updates)
                print(chat_id)

                send_message(output, chat_id)
                time.sleep(0.1)

                last_update_id =+ 1 #returns max_id in the json file and adds 1
                continue
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed - it is called "print debuging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: maybe you should first check `if  get_last_update_id(updates)  != last_update_id`

Comment: Thanks @furas for your comment.

I managed to fix it by adding a break in the loop so it goes to a higher loop.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by adding a break in the loop so it loops back to the outside 'while' loop. Below is the edited code:

```py
# chatbot.py module imported above this line not included. It trains NN model. 

import json 
import requests
import time
import urllib
import telegram

TOKEN = "XXX"
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)


def get_url(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        content = response.content.decode("utf8")
        return content

def get_json_from_url(url):
        content = get_url(url)
        js = json.loads(content)
        return js


def get_updates(offset): #gets json file from URL
        url = URL + "getUpdates"
        if offset:
                url += "?offset={}".format(offset)
        js = get_json_from_url(url)
        return js

def get_last_update_id(updates):
        update_ids = []
        for update in updates["result"]:
                update_ids.append(update["update_id"])
        return max(update_ids, default = last_update_id)

def get_last_chat_text(updates):
        # num_updates = len(updates["result"])
        # last_update = num_updates - 1
        text = updates["result"][-1]["message"]["text"] #text input
        return text

def get_last_chat_id(updates):
        chat_id = updates["result"][-1]["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        return chat_id


def send_message(output,chat_id):
        bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text = output)

def main():
        input_text = get_last_chat_text(updates)
        return input_text                

bot_name = "XXX"
print("Let's chat! (type 'quit' to exit)")
last_update_id = 0
while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_update_id) #returns json file

        for last_update_id in updates["result"]:
                main()
                input_text = main()
                if input_text == "quit":
                        break
                input_text = tokenize(input_text)
                X = bag_of_words(input_text, all_words)
                X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
                X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

                output = model(X)
                _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

                tag = tags[predicted.item()]

                probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
                prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
                if prob.item() > 0.75:
                        for intent in intents['intents']:
                                if tag == intent["tag"]:
                                        output = f"{random.choice(intent['responses'])}"
                else:
                        output = f"{bot_name}: I do not understand..."

                print(output)

                chat_id = get_last_chat_id(updates)
                print(chat_id)

                send_message(output, chat_id)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        
                break
        last_update_id = get_last_update_id(updates) + 1 #returns max_id in the json file and adds 1
```

Comment: you should can get the same result using only first element from list `last_update_id = updates["result"][0]` without using `for`-loop and `break`

Comment: Do you mean the line above "while True"? In that case, the first loop iteration will have "updates" not defined as the first loop requires a default value for last_update_id to use define "updates"

Comment: inside `while True` but without `for last_update_id in updates["result"]:` because using `break` at the end of this `for`-loop you run it only once and you can do the same using `last_update_id = updates["result"][0]`